# Windows event logging with log4j2 in Java

Tags: java, windows, log4j2, event-log

I cannot find any good example about how to do windows event logging with log4j2.

Is it possible? My application can do it with log4j 1, but I want to upgrade to log4j2. And I need windows event logging also.

Any help or example would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is: **log4jna**

And it works just perfectly.

https://github.com/dblock/log4jna